# apt-daily.service takes 20 min: Ubuntu 16.04 slow boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, suspend, hibernate

I have Ubuntu 16.04LTS and today, I was experiencing very slow resume.
So, I ran **systemd-analyze blame**
And the results were:

```
20min 58.054s apt-daily.service
 1min 3.335s sendmail.service
     38.761s mysql.service
     27.554s systemd-rfkill.service
     18.918s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     12.038s ModemManager.service
     10.571s dev-sda8.device
      9.204s wpa_supplicant.service
      8.921s accounts-daemon.service
      7.911s grub-common.service
      7.187s apport.service
      7.162s irqbalance.service
      7.062s networking.service
      7.038s ondemand.service
      6.770s systemd-logind.service
      6.743s speech-dispatcher.service
      6.706s sysstat.service
      6.646s lm-sensors.service
      6.639s alsa-restore.service
      6.511s gpu-manager.service
      6.493s avahi-daemon.service
      6.480s pppd-dns.service
      6.476s rsyslog.service
      6.473s systemd-user-sessions.service
      6.234s snapd.autoimport.service
      5.940s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-09E2\x2d89F7.service
      4.419s apparmor.service
      3.475s NetworkManager.service
      3.330s plymouth-read-write.service
      2.191s lightdm.service
      2.038s systemd-udevd.service
      1.959s polkitd.service
      1.857s plymouth-start.service
      1.727s mnt-27EDE16A355CF599.mount
      1.237s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.180s keyboard-setup.service
      1.130s apache2.service
      1.124s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       988ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       924ms bluetooth.service
       871ms systemd-journald.service
       784ms console-setup.service
       699ms upower.service
       656ms dev-mqueue.mount
       582ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       527ms udisks2.service
       487ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       479ms ufw.service
       463ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       455ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       421ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
       418ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       402ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       398ms colord.service
       376ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       325ms fancontrol.service
       302ms thermald.service
       280ms phpsessionclean.service
       232ms systemd-random-seed.service
       198ms dev-hugepages.mount
       189ms dev-sda9.swap
       173ms logmein-hamachi.service
       172ms systemd-sysctl.service
       167ms resolvconf.service
       167ms setvtrgb.service
       166ms dns-clean.service
       146ms boot-efi.mount
        96ms rc-local.service
        74ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        68ms rtkit-daemon.service
        31ms user@1000.service
        13ms snapd.socket
         9ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         6ms ureadahead-stop.service
         4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         2ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
```

And, the Results of systemd-analyze critical-chain were:

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 57.100s
└─multi-user.target @1min 57.100s
  └─cups-browsed.service @5min 30.739s
    └─cups.service @5min 30.738s
      └─basic.target @24.702s
        └─sockets.target @24.702s
          └─snapd.socket @24.676s +13ms
            └─sysinit.target @24.606s
              └─apparmor.service @20.167s +4.419s
                └─local-fs.target @19.979s
                  └─media-Windows-D.mount @4min 44.168s
                    └─dev-sda3.device @17.200s
```

What can I do to solve the problem? Please help!